# db.insert is returning -1 while inserting data to sqlite database

Tags: android, android-studio

my activity2.java file is as below:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper vipDB;

    public Button btnAddData;
    public EditText Name,Email,Phone,Prayer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
        vipDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
        Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextEmailAddress2);
        Phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone2);
        Prayer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName2);
        btnAddData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        SubmitPrayerRequest();
    }

    public void SubmitPrayerRequest() {
        btnAddData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name = Name.getText().toString();
                String email = Email.getText().toString();
                String phone = Phone.getText().toString();
                String prayer = Prayer.getText().toString();

                boolean insertData = vipDB.SubmitPrayer(name, email, phone,prayer);

                if (insertData == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, "Data Successfully Inserted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, "Something went wrong :(.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and my DatabaseHelper.java file is as below:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "vip.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Prayers_table";
    public static final String COL1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL2 = "Name";
    public static final String COL3 = "Email";
    public static final String COL4 = "Phone";
    public static final String COL5 = "Prayer";



    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                " NAME TEXT, EMAIL VARCHAR, PHONE VARCHAR, PRAYER VARCHAR )";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP  TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public boolean SubmitPrayer(String name, String email, String phone ,String prayer){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(COL2,name);
        contentValues.put(COL3,email);
        contentValues.put(COL4,phone);
        contentValues.put(COL5,prayer);
        


        long result  = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

can someone please tell me why my insert function is always returning -1?(when I debug I am able to see contentvalues= "Prayer=please Name=chris Email=chris@gmail.com Phone=123456")
looks like the last column has become first

Please help!

Comment: hey, I don't see any problem with the code, in android studio open device file explorer go into data->data->app.package->databases->vip.db right click on it and save it on your desktop, if you don't see the database there then it was never created but if it is use this website https://sqliteonline.com/ and upload the database to check if the structure is laid out how you expect it to be, if it is try running the insert query in this website, it should tell what went wrong.

Comment: So, tried checking if the db was there, saw many dbs there(as I was constantly changing the name), I deleted all  of them and ran the app and entered data and it successfully inserted !  I could see the same thing happen again ( insert failing and working again after deletion of db) after a couple of entries. Any idea why that is happening? memory problems?

Comment: Make sure you're not creating a new database from else where and the version of the database is the same, there is simply no reason for android to create new databases until its told do, it is impossible for me tell since I can't see your whole project but if it is creating multiple databases it is because you're it to do so.